# PyTorch: AssertionError ("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried using pytorch with my GPU, but I alway get the error `AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled`

Here are the environment information for torch:

```
PyTorch version: 1.11.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.7.64
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Nvidia driver version: 516.01
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.21.5
[pip3] torch==1.11.0
[pip3] torchaudio==0.11.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.12.0
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
[conda] mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
[conda] mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_0
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h277e83a_0
[conda] mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hf11a4ad_0
[conda] numpy                     1.21.5           py39h7a0a035_2
[conda] numpy-base                1.21.5           py39hca35cd5_2
[conda] pytorch                   1.11.0              py3.9_cpu_0    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
[conda] torchaudio                0.11.0                 py39_cpu    pytorch
[conda] torchvision               0.12.0                 py39_cpu    pytorch
```

As you can see, I installed CUDA 11.7

I tried installing different versions of pytorch and cudatoolkit, but nothing works.

What else can I do, to make it work?

Comment: You have a non-GPU enabled version of Pytorch installed, as the error is clearly telling you. You need to install a GPU enabled version.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was not aware of that since I thougt I installed the GPU enabled version using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use cuda 11.6

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116
```

If you want to use stable version with the last version cuda compiled cuda 11.5

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu115
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).